# PHP MySql trying to get number of last row

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table with two columns "Number" and "Date". I want retrieve the value of the last row however this isn't working:

```
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT Number FROM functions_order_numbers ORDER BY Number DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Number"];
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Table:
[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUjw0.png)

I'm trying to create an incremental unique order number

Comment: `SELECT ifnull(max(Number),0) FROM functions_order_numbers`. But have you ever heard of `auto_increment`?

Comment: If `Number` is auto-incrementing why do you need to do this, if not why not make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an incremental number in the table, then use `auto_increment`:

```
create table t (
    number int auto_increment primary key,  -- usually it is a primary key
    . . .
);
```

Don't attempt to do this at the application layer.  It is dangerous, because multiple updates at the same time might not do the right thing.